# Make permanent changes in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, nomodeset

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

`uname -a`

```
Linux username-laptop 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have to manually add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash $vt_handoff` by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> during the grub. Instead of doing this manually, I want to make a permanent change.
I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/38782/1013762) but it wouldn't solve the problem as it adds `nomodeset` between `quiet splash` and `$vt_handoff` and Ubuntu gets stuck on boot screen:

[image: grub]

How can I do this?

Comment: Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (as root, e.g. `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg`)

Comment: @MaxSilvester can you explain to me how exactly I need to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had done previously, First I opened `/etc/default/grub`:

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/grub
```

Then I changed the line -`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update grub2
```

But after several restarts (adding nomodeset manually everytime), this finally worked.